# How to join and group 2 tables with a comma list in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have two array which have the following objects:

```
$dataset1 = @(
    @{
        MachineName = "AAA"
        ID   = "111"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "BBB"
        ID   = "222"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "CCC"
        ID   = "111"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "DDD"
        ID   = "333"
    },
    @{
        MachineName = "EEE"
        ID   = "111"
    }
)

$dataset2 = @(
    @{
        ID      = "111"
        TagName = "ALPHA2"
    },
    @{
        ID      = "222"
        TagName = "ALPHA0"
    },
    @{
        ID      = "333"
        TagName = "ALPHA8"
    },
    @{
        ID      = "444"
        TagName = "ALPHA29"
    },
)
```

Now I want to create an array which have an object of TagName and for each object of TagName it should contain a list of MachineNames separated by comma so something like this:

```
TagName | MachineName 

ALPHA2    AAA,CCC,EEE

ALPHA0    BBB

ALPHA8    DDD
```

This is the code that I have tried:

```
$Joined= Foreach ($row in $dataset1)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        
        ID   = $row.ID   
        MachineName = $row.MachineName -join ','
        TagName = $dataset2 | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq $row.ID} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TagName 

    }
}
```

But it is not generating a comma list of Machine names instead it is printing individual rows for each machine name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate `$dataset2` instead of `$dataset1`.

```
$joined = foreach($row in $dataset2){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TagName     = $row.tagname
        MachineName = ($dataset1 | Where-Object id -eq $row.id).MachineName -join ','
    }
}
```

If you're trying to exclude those entries in `$dataset1` that don't have a corresponding entry in `$dataset2`, change to this.

```
$joined = foreach($row in $dataset2 | Where-Object id -in $dataset1.id){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TagName     = $row.tagname
        MachineName = ($dataset1 | Where-Object id -eq $row.id).MachineName -join ','
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> it is not generating a comma list of Machine names instead it is printing individual rows for each machine name.

That's actually a great starting point!

Just pipe the resulting objects to `Group-Object` and extract the machine names from each resulting group:

```
$joined |Group-Object TagName |Select Name,@{Name='Machines';Expression = {$_.Group.MachineName -join ','}}
```

Which should give you something like:

```
Name   Machines
----   --------
ALPHA2 AAA,CCC,EEE
ALPHA0 BBB
ALPHA8 DDD
```